# Process Javascript before saving to Database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Hello I have an array of data in the following format

http://pastebin.com/NeS4DaAn

The data contains address, phone numbers and some tags. There is a special Javascript value in the array within `document.write`, that when executed produce an email address. I want to save this data in a MySQL database using PHP, but with the actual email address not with the Javascript code and I am not able to figure out, how to do it ?

Comment: I'm assuming the pastebin represents HTML form data submitted to PHP.  Can you post some information about the form itself, and about how it is generated?  Parsing the string in PHP will work, but I think the real fix is to change whatever is putting Javascript code into a form input value, but we can't provide any pointers on that without this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Send JS to the server then do

```
 $decodedJS= html_entity_decode($myJS);

function extract_emails_from($string){
    preg_match_all("/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $string, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}

$email = extract_emails_from($decodedJS);
```

Comment: This worked great, here's the output http://pastebin.com/1D8TFcBY, Can you also tell me how can I extract the email addresses and other data from this multidimension array. The email is located at different indexed in the array :)